# DirectX11 engine: Compile errors C2719, C2678

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am currently working on my final project for my Cpp class, which involves working with directX11 to create a 2D game. I have been following tutorials from the website rastertek.com (directX 11 series 2), and for the most part it has been going pretty smoothly. However the portion of code on shaders I finished up this morning had some errors right away.

At first it was giving me error C2719 in my colorshaderclass.cpp at lines 44 and 248 with my XMMATRIX values being passed in. After some quick research on the topic I changed those XMMATRIX values being passed in to constant references. I then went into my `colorshaderclass.h` file and changed the XMMATRIX values on lines 37 and 44 to constant references as necessary.

After doing that I no longer have error C2719 showing up. However now I am getting error C2678 (binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const DirectX::XMMATRIX'), on lines 256, 257, and 258 of my colorshaderclass.cpp file. I've done a bit of research on this error too but it seems to be very situation dependent and I have had no luck with it.

Actually, I should say I think I understand why it is throwing the error (const on one side, a non-constant on the other), but I am stumped on what to do at this point as I had to make parts of the code into constant references to get them to work. I should also mention that I have less than six months of programming experience at this point, so sorry if this seems like an obvious fix or anything. If anybody has any insight or ideas it would be much appreciated. 
Cheers!

There are also several other parts to the whole solution I can provide if needed, although none of them were throwing any errors.

The offending code is below (C2678)

```
worldMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(worldMatrix);
    viewMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(viewMatrix);
    projectionMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(projectionMatrix);
```

and the XMMATRIX values I changed to constant references:

```
bool ColorShaderClass::SetShaderParameters(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, const XMMATRIX& worldMatrix, const XMMATRIX& viewMatrix, const XMMATRIX& projectionMatrix)

bool ColorShaderClass::Render(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, int indexCount, const XMMATRIX& worldMatrix, const XMMATRIX& viewMatrix, const XMMATRIX& projectionMatrix)
```

And what I changed in the header file

```
bool Render(ID3D11DeviceContext*Int, int, const XMMATRIX&, const XMMATRIX&, const XMMATRIX&);

bool SetShaderParameters(ID3D11DeviceContext*, const XMMATRIX&, const XMMATRIX&, const XMMATRIX&);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your report exactly what all the variable types are. Is your `worldMatrix` declared as `XMFLOAT4X4`? Both `XMVECTOR` and `XMMATRIX` have alignment requirements, so it is not recommended to use them directly as class/struct variables. If you are following that advice, then you need to use `XMStoreFloat4x4` and `XMLoadFloat4x4` to convert between `XMFLOAT4X4` and `XMMATRIX`.

So a typical usage would be something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 m_worldMatrix;
};

// ...

void MyClass::SomeFunction()
{
   XMMATRIX worldMatrix = XMLoadFloat4x4( &m_worldMatrix );

   // do some stuff with worldMatrix as an ``XMMATRIX``

   XMStoreFloat4x4( &m_worldMatrix, worldMatrix );
}
```

Yes this is verbose, but intentionally. Most of the loss of performance when doing SIMD programming is converting to and from non-aligned and/or scalar types. This pattern encourages the advanced programmer to load the values into 'register proxy' types (`XMMATRIX`, `XMVECTOR`) and then do a lot of operations as such before storing them back into scalar or non-aligned types.

If you like the convenience of the C++ operator overloading, then take a look at [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK). It provides some classes that 'wrap' DirectXMath so that it's more intuitive to use. It does have some performance implications, but unless you are really performance sensitive you won't notice. It is also very easy to intermix SimpleMath and DirectXMath types. The above example would be:

```
class MyClass
{
   DirectX::SimpleMath::Matrix m_worldMatrix;
};

// ...

void MyClass::SomeFunction()
{
    XMMATRIX worldMatrix = m_worldMatrix;

    // do some stuff with worldMatrix as an ``XMMATRIX``
    // or just use the methods and operator overloads directly
    // of the ``Matrix`` SimpleMath type

    m_worldMatrix = worldMatrix;
}
```

As for your parameter usage, you certainly can use const ref's like you are doing, but you might find it helpful to use the various DirectXMath calling-convention types described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418728.aspx#Call_Conventions). For your example, it would end up as:

```
bool XM_CALLCONV ColorShaderClass::SetShaderParameters(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, FXMMATRIX worldMatrix, CXMMATRIX viewMatrix, CXMMATRIX projectionMatrix)
```

> This is not strictly necessary, but if you are trying to leverage the various SIMD-friendly calling conventions across x86 __fastcall, x86 __vectorcall, x64 __fastcall, x64 __vectorcall, and ARM these types and the `XM_CALLCONV` macro can achieve that.